# Hijacking another processes form

Tags: c#, .net, forms

So, I have been asked to figure out a way to make a program containing sensitive data more secure since we have staff that go afk and put potentially put data at risk.

I have loaded up Visual Studio for C# and found a nice way to get process of the fore mentioned application. Then grab the main window and attach a panel of my very own. This panel will basically now be used like a blind covering the application when its not in use.

Now, I have a program running in system tray waiting for the sensitive data to come on screen and my little panel hijacks the entire window and now nothing can be seen.

My problem now is how ever, that whilst my panel is attacked the main window of the application i am trying to lock out seems to just crash. I am guessing that is because my panel and the application belong to different processes.

Anyway I could do with some advise here.

Here is my panels class.

```
class LockingPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
    private IntPtr prn;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    public void SetParent(IntPtr parent)
    {
        prn = parent;
        SetParent(this.Handle, prn);
    }

    public IntPtr GetParent() {
        return prn;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT Rect);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
        public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
        public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
        public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
    }

    public void FillParent()
    {
        RECT rtc = new RECT();
        GetWindowRect(prn, ref rtc);
        this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(rtc.Right, rtc.Bottom);

    }
```

Anybody got a better idea on how I can go about this, or at least make it so that my panel inst going to crash the application.

Comment: GetLastInputInfo() will let you make a decision as to whether on not the user is afk, if so LockWorkstation()

Comment: just set the PC to automatically lock the screen after a couple of minutes inactivity. Control it via group policy so user can't mess with it. And also train your users about data protection and enforce the rules with implications. Leaving the screen open is not the only way users leak sensitive data.

Comment: Sadly that is not a viable option, this is for an education environment and the machines being used are still be used as white boards, we tried a workstation lock out but unfortunately it heavily effects the users ability to teach. Right now I just need to figure out how to stop my program from crashing.

Comment: There could be a number of reasons why the application is crashing, you need to narrow it down, however why don't you just minimize it

Comment: Well, the issue there is that teachers leave the class rooms and don't exit the application. The students then take this opportunity to jump on maximize the application and distribute bad marks and detentions. Nothing less then fully locking the user out of the application after 5 minutes (with a accompanying unlock procedure), allowing the desktop to still be usable for white board, email, etc.

Comment: Then the teachers need to lock the workstation and/or exit the application when they leave the room. Again it's a training and cultural issue. Punish teachers who break the rules and any students who take advantage of their careless behaviour. Also consider whether teachers should even running this kind of application on a machine which students could potentially access. Who runs a marking / detention application on a whiteboard? Switch the whiteboard off or use another device.

Comment: By trying to create a technical workaround you're just allowing a cultural problem to persist and letting people get away with not caring about the students' sensitive information. Teachers, if they care about their pupils, should want to pay attention to this. Eventually someone will work round your workaround. The problem won't go away until you change the culture and awareness of the users. It's in many ways a classic X-Y problem.

Comment: Sorry but I am asking for help to tackle an issue, A programming issue. Whilst this way might not be the most logical process unfortunately as somebody asked to do A job, I am expected to do that job. I am how ever not going to turn around to a huge client and tell them to train their staff better. Teachers are not like us programmers they have ZERO sense of logic and asking them to exit an application before leaving a room is like asking them to saw of their own heads with a dinner knife.

Comment: What happens if your program is killed? Defeating your "solution" seems trivial.

Comment: Witch would require a student to have admin access to open task manager and kill the service. Good job a thing called Group Policy exists, can we stop poking holes into my assigned task and help me complete it. If it turns out to be a useless and unimplementable piece of garbage so be it, as long as it matches the request of the client then nobody can yell at me for not doing my job. As of right now If i turn to my manager and say this idea is dumb then I will be fired.

Comment: Then your manager is an idiot, not to put too fine a point on it. They should be challenging the client that this is a bad idea. It's technically difficult to do, as you've discovered, and is just replacing a real-world problem with a technical one (hence an "X-Y" problem). If a student has gained unauthorised physical access to a machine under a teacher's username then it should be a breach of the school's security policy and the teacher gets disciplined or fired, not you.

Comment: You should be challenging your manager to to challenge the client. If your manager can't take constructive criticism or work with the client to find a better solution (instead of just blindly agreeing to implement something which isn't a good solution for the problem and seemingly without checking it was technically feasible), then they are a bad manager.

Comment: Its not about the manager its about filling the needs of the client, this is a proof of concept nothing more. I just need to show a basic version of this that can then be used to demo to the client how awful it is. Anyway if your going to answer with another debunk then don't bother, unless your actually willing to help tackle the issue. Absolute waste of my time.

Comment: If you _really_ have to do this bizarre scheme, then have you checked what is causing the app to crash? Probably something's logged in the event viewer. Have you also considered as well, rather than hijacking the app and attaching more forms to it, just finding the app's position on screen and placing your form directly above it at the right size and not movable. If the user tries to switch task to the other app, try and detect this and disallow, or immediately switch back to your program, equally get them to sync minimising/maximising if you can. Not sure if it works but it's worth trying

Comment: OTOH If it's just a POC then you can legitimately say to the client "it doesn't work technically, look it crashes, think of something else". BTW Debunking isn't a waste of time if it stops you pursuing something which _is_ a waste of time. You're not the only person on this forum who, when asked "how do I get to there" is given the answer "Well I wouldn't start from here". I see it all the time.

Comment: So the app crashes because the 2 applications exist in separate threads. When i try to interact with the application it crashes immediately throwing a System.InvalidOperationException, the message of witch is ' Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on'. So i need to figure out a way to get this program to run in the same thread.

Comment: In regards to the idea of having an unmovable form constantly positioned on top of the window. I tried this already and had a lot of issues keeping the panel above the window in a way that lets other windows be onpenover the top of and not obscured.

Comment: Surely it doesn't matter if anything else is obscured because it's meant to only be on when the machine is not supposed to be in use by anyone?

Comment: The machine can still be in use, i just need to lock out the one application and allow the pc to still be usable. Obviously I cant pause or close the application because its often used by the tutors to run reports and stuff.

Comment: I thought the issue was the teacher leaving the room, so in that case surely the machine is not still in use? The students should not be using it?

Comment: Anyway I don't see how you can get a program to insert itself into or manipulate a program running in another thread - especially if they're not even running under the same identity (user vs admin in a service) - that would sound like a hacker's dream. Your intentions are good but if it was _your_ app you wouldn't want other applications able to interfere with it.

Comment: I don't know if https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls would help when it's not within the same application, but that's all I can find about your error which seems vaguely relevant

Comment: Thank you, that appears to be the issue. All i need to do is figure out how to get the invoke method of the IntPtr in c#. Google is not giving me anything helpful with that, still i continue searching.